# GD установлено и не работает

Tags: php, gd, php5

Добрый вечер, понадобилась либа GD для PHP 5.6 на Debian 8.
[image: Установил, проверил.]
Вроде как должна работать, но нет.
При попытке юзать функции либы кидает ошибку, мол не знаем таких.

Comment: Что выведет результат выполнения такого: var_dump(gd_info()); И желательно пример ошибки

Comment: @АнтонСкородумов ответ на 2 вопроса в одном флаконе: ```Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function gd_info() in /var/www/html/try.php:2
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/try.php on line 2```

Comment: А такой пакет у Вас на сервере установлен libgd3 Посмотреть можно dpkg -l | grep libgd3

Comment: @АнтонСкородумов да, ответ на команду: ```ii  libgd3:amd64                          2.1.0-5+deb8u11                    amd64        GD Graphics Library```